# Changing columns to rows layout with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay-theme

Good morning!

I'm doing a layout in which I have 4 columns. In these 4 columns first is the image, just below your title and description. This aspect must be kept in desktop and tablet mode. At this point I have no problem

[image: modeDesktop]

CODE: http://www.bootply.com/Sv6rAEA9Jz

Change comes when mobile mode, you are 4 columns have to become 1 column with 4 rows. Example:

[image: modeMobile]

The image must be to the left and right description.

I do not know how to do this in mobile mode

Can somebody help me?

greetings from Spain

Comment: what you tried so far? post your code / create a demo.. so others can help you...

Comment: I have the code in question @G.L.P .  Is this: http://www.bootply.com/Sv6rAEA9Jz  .you can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Sv6rAEA9Jz)**

After every `col-**-**`, try to add `row div` to get your content to expanded fully along with the code added here

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  
  <div class="cajaContenido col-sm-12">
    <div class="imagenContenido col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://hdwallpaperspretty.com/wp-content/gallery/hd-background-1920x1080/1920x1080%20Wallpaper%20128.jpg" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1456387393358_870">
    </div>
    <div class="textoContenido col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
      <div class="contenidoUr">
        <h5>ESTUDIOS DE GRADO</h5>
        <p>Estudios y proyectos en la cuna del rioja</p>
      </div>
    </div>      
  </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Skype.svg/256px-Skype.svg.png" alt="image1" class="img-responsive" style="min-width: 128px; max-width: 128px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-8">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Description about the image goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Skype.svg/256px-Skype.svg.png" alt="image1" class="img-responsive" style="min-width: 128px; max-width: 128px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-8">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Description about the image goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Skype.svg/256px-Skype.svg.png" alt="image1" class="img-responsive" style="min-width: 128px; max-width: 128px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-8">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Description about the image goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Skype.svg/256px-Skype.svg.png" alt="image1" style="min-width: 128px; max-width: 128px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-8">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Description about the image goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/5zmq7mn1/)